# What are the implications of Python integers not being limited by 32 or 64 bit size?

Tags: python, integer, bit-manipulation

There's a bit manipulation problem that asks you to sum up two integers without using + or - operators. Below is the code in Java:

```
public int getSum(int a, int b) {
    while (b != 0) {
        int carry = a & b;
        a = a ^ b;
        b = carry << 1;
    }
    return a;
}
```

When you try to sum up -1 and 1, the intermediate values take on [-2, 2], [-4, 4] and so on until the number overflows and the result reaches 0. You can't do the same in Python, the process goes on forever taking up an entire CPU thread and slowly growing in memory. It seems that on my machine the numbers will grow for a while until no memory is left.

```
def getSum(a, b):
    while c != 0:
        carry = a & b
        a = a ^ b
        b = carry << 1
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print getSum(-1, 1) # will run forever
```

This is rather peculiar example, are there any real-world implications of not having the integers limited in size?

Comment: The real-world implication is that you don't have to write awful unreadable code which uses bitshift hacks to do arithmetic.  You just write basic math and it just works ..

Comment: You don't get silent misbehavior when you end up needing bigger integers than you expected.

Comment: What do you mean by 'implications', exactly? The only real implication is that you have to be careful. Are you looking for something more specific? If so, what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the implications are that you must **know** and **enforce** your own integer widths when computing checksums

you make it the size you want

```
carry = (a & b)&255
a = (a ^ b)&255
b = (carry << 1)&255
```

would be one byte wide integers ...

Comment: Although this is a good point, it does not answer the question at all.

Comment: how does this not answer the question ... you have to enforce sizes if you are trying to implement  checksums ... thats all there is too it ...